# Send data from an API to google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I was working in a project which is converting some data to another table by an online API (web service), so the plan is fetching data from the API and converting the prices to another table, I still got the same error again and again which is not convert each row as the way I need.
SCREENSHOT : [UI FOR THE SPREADSHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwqQs.png)
CODE :

```
function Send_Button() {

  //activate the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cellCurrency = spreadsheet.getRange('E9').getValues();

  //fatching the data from the API
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base="+cellCurrency).getContentText();

  //parsing data to JSON
  var json = JSON.parse(res);

  //exporting data in variables
  var USD=json['rates']['USD'],
      CAD=json['rates']['CAD'],
      GBP=json['rates']['GBP'],
      EUR=json['rates']['EUR'];

  //an array to fetch just 4 currencies
  var CRN = [USD,CAD,GBP,EUR];
  var cellsPrice = spreadsheet.getRange('E5:E8').getValues();

  //targeted cell in the second currencies table
    var cellsTraget1 = spreadsheet.getRange('H3:K3');
    var cellsTraget2 = spreadsheet.getRange('H4:K4');
    var cellsTraget3 = spreadsheet.getRange('H5:K5');
    var cellsTraget4 = spreadsheet.getRange('H6:K6');

//converting process
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {

    cellsTraget1.setValue(cellsPrice[0]*CRN[0]);
    cellsTraget2.setValue(cellsPrice[1]*CRN[1]);
    cellsTraget3.setValue(cellsPrice[2]*CRN[2]);
    cellsTraget4.setValue(cellsPrice[3]*CRN[3]);

  }



}
```

Comment: what happens if you Logger.log(CRN[3]);

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script code:

```
function Send_Button() {

  //activate the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cellCurrency = spreadsheet.getRange('E10').getValue();

  //fatching the data from the API
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base="+cellCurrency).getContentText();

  //parsing data to JSON
  var json = JSON.parse(res);

  //exporting data in variables
  var USD=json['rates']['USD'],
      CAD=json['rates']['CAD'],
      GBP=json['rates']['GBP'],
      EUR=json['rates']['EUR'];

  //an array to fetch just 4 currencies
  var CRN = [USD,CAD,GBP,EUR];
  var cellsPrice = spreadsheet.getRange('E5:E8').getValues();

  //targeted cell in the second currencies table
  var targetRange = spreadsheet.getRange('H3:K6');
  var targetValues = targetRange.getValues();

  //converting process
  for(var i=0;i<cellsPrice.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<CRN.length;j++) {
      targetValues[i][j] = cellsPrice[i][0]*CRN[j];
    }
  }

  targetRange.setValues(targetValues);
};
```

You can also get the similar result using function **[GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en)**, try:

```
=mmult(E5:E8,{googlefinance("USDEUR"),googlefinance("USDCAD"),googlefinance("USDGBP")})
```